# How do I delete rows from a table on a linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I need to delete rows from a table in several databases on several servers with the same schema. [OPENROWSET()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) does not seem to be the answer.

If I do this:

```
SET @sqlStr = '
    SELECT TOP 0 * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=' + @Server + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
        ''DELETE FROM [' + @DBName + '].dbo.tblName WHERE foo='bar') AS a';
EXEC (@sqlStr);
```

I get the error

```
Msg 11525, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1
The metadata could not be determined because statement 'DELETE FROM  . . .
```

If I add `SELECT 1;` to the query so a resultset gets returned like i do below, I get one row one column result (the value of which is BTW not '1'). However, there delete operation does not occur.

```
SET @sqlStr = '
    SELECT TOP 0 * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=' + @Server + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
        ''SELECT 1; DELETE FROM [' + @DBName + '].dbo.tblName WHERE foo='bar') AS a';
EXEC (@sqlStr);
```

What do I need to make the delete happen on the linked server?

Comment: I don't understand `SELECT TOP 0 *` or why you want `OPENROWSET` for this. Much simpler to just use the linked server directly, instead of trying to turn a non-query into a query, no?

Comment: Alternative to using a linke server: Use PowerShell to loop through a server & database list calling invoke-sqlcmd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'DELETE [' + @DBName + '].dbo.tblname WHERE foo = ''bar'';';
EXEC linkedserver...sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Because I didn't know that was possible and didn't think that EXEC could do that. THANKS!

Comment: Or just do: DELETE T FROM Server.Database.Schema.Table AS T WHERE ......

Comment: But @RobertLDavis did you notice that `@DBName` was a parameter? Also what value does the alias `T` provide?